# The meaning of 있다는 것

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> 우리가 검사를 해서 문제가 있**다**는 것을 깨달았어요.
>
> 근데 검사를 언제 했어요?

(The example is from [the following page](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-76-83/lesson-77/))

I don't understand why that sentence uses 다 between 있 and 는. If you strip it and make the sentence to the following, I think it is just fine.

> 우리가 검사를 해서 문제가 있는 것을 깨달았어요.

So what is the purpose of 다 in that sentence and why is it used as such?

Comment: I think it stresses the fact that something was discovered, as opposed to just stating that something was discovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, -다는 is the abbreviation of -다고 하는, which is the reason there is 다. -다는, however, is not always the same as -다고 하는 now (Note: 하다 here means 말하다, 생각하다, or their related words).

These are two kinds of adnominal clauses:

> A. 문제가 있다는
>
> B. 문제가 있는

In the form of an indirect quotation, "문제가 있다는" modifies 것; however, "문제가 있는" directly modifies it. Because 것 in your sentences is equivalent to 사실 ("the fact"), A and B are semantically the same [(reference)](http://inhakorean.or.kr/onboard.php?bname=qna&mode=view&idx=108&current_page=2).

It is important to know that the noun determines which clause can come before it. Let's consider these, too:

> C. 저는 친구가 오**는** 것을 느꼈어요.
>
> D. 저는 친구가 온**다는** 것을 느꼈어요.
>
> E. 저는 친구가 오**는** 것을 봤어요.
>
> F. 저는 친구가 온**다는** 것을 봤어요. (✘)
>
> G. 저는 친구가 오**는** 얘기를 들었어요. (✘)
>
> H. 저는 친구가 온**다는** 얘기를 들었어요.

것 for C and D means 사실; 것 for E and F means 모습 (In my opinion, 것 should be avoided to clarify the meaning). C and D are the same in meaning (As a sidenote, "저는 친구가 온다고 느꼈어요." is also correct). It is, nevertheless, *incorrect* to say "저는 친구가 온**다고 하는** 것을 느꼈어요.", so the clause in D does not have the real function of an indirect quotation. The clause in your first example sentence closely relates to D because no one would say "... 문제가 있다고 하는 것을 깨달았어요." F and G are *incorrect*; they show difference between the two kinds. H is the same as "저는 친구가 온**다고 하는** 얘기를 들었어요."; therefore, H has the clause as an indirect quotation.

---

Your example sentences sound a bit awkward. Instead of them, I would say:

- 우리는 검사를 해서 문제를 발견했어요.
- 우리는 검사로 문제점을 찾았어요.